# How to implement a Qt-like Property system?

Tags: c++, qt

I've been using Qt for a while now and I find fascinating how their Property system works.

```
QPushButton *button = new QPushButton; // inherits a QObject
button->setProperty("down", true);
button->setProperty("angle", 35.0);

QVariant value = button->property("angle");
```

I started wondering how I could implement it. What makes it possible to be so easy to use?

Comment: read the source.

Comment: You will need to implement a `Variant` type that can hold arbitrary data types, then it is as simple as a map with a string for key as the property name, and the corresponding variant for the value. This is actually quite inefficient and has lots of overhead. Only recommended if you really need that amount of dynamism. Better just use Qt, no need to reinvent the wheel.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Your question in its current form is too broad and cannot be answer within the scope of SO. Please visit the [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help) and read the section [how do I ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: @KarolyHorvath - actually that would hardly be the best or even adequate way to understand the concept.

Comment: Given that the property system's code is trivial - yes, reading the source would give insight into how to implement one using Qt types.

Comment: @KubaOber - I am sure it is trivial, especially the integration with the meta system, the moc code generation and whatnot. Casual read to anyone who is fascinated by and can't figure how to map a string to a value ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you have a suitable variant class, it's easy. All you need is a map from names to variants:

```
#include <map>
#include <string>
#include <cassert>
#include <boost/variant.hpp>

class WithProperties {
public:
    using variant = boost::variant<std::string, int, double, bool>;
    template <typename T> T property(const char * name) const {
        auto it = m_properties.find(name);
        if (it != m_properties.end()) return boost::get<T>(it->second);
        return T{};
    }
    void setProperty(const char * name, const variant & value) {
        m_properties[name] = value;
    }
    std::vector<std::string> propertyNames() const {
        std::vector<std::string> keys;
        keys.reserve(m_properties.size());
        for (auto prop : m_properties)
            keys.push_back(prop.first);
        return keys;
    }
private:
    std::map<std::string, variant> m_properties;
};

int main() {
    WithProperties prop;
    prop.setProperty("down", true);
    prop.setProperty("angle", 35.0);
    prop.setProperty("name", std::string{"foo"});
    assert(prop.property<bool>("down") == true);
    assert(prop.property<double>("angle") == 35.0);
    assert(prop.property<std::string>("name") == "foo");
}
```

If you're wondering how it's done using Qt's types, it's even easier, because `QVariant` implements helpful `operator==` *and* constructor that knows how to deal with all basic C value types.

```
#include <QtCore>

class WithProperties {
public:
    QVariant property(const char * name) const {
        auto it = m_properties.find(name);
        if (it != m_properties.end()) return *it;
        return QVariant{};
    }
    void setProperty(const char * name, const QVariant & value) {
        m_properties[name] = value;
    }
    QList<QByteArray> propertyNames() const {
        return m_properties.keys();
    }
private:
    QMap<QByteArray, QVariant> m_properties;
};

int main() {
    WithProperties prop;
    prop.setProperty("down", true);
    prop.setProperty("angle", 35.0);
    prop.setProperty("name", "foo");
    Q_ASSERT(prop.property("down") == true);
    Q_ASSERT(prop.property("angle") == 35.0);
    Q_ASSERT(prop.property("name") == "foo");
}
```

Qt's property system does one more thing: it uses the staticly-named properties declared using `Q_PROPERTY`. These are available via metadata, and are integrated with dynamic properties as seen above. You could implement it as follows (this is not copied from Qt code):

```
#include <QtCore>
#include <cstring>

QMetaProperty findMetaProperty(const QMetaObject * obj, const char * name) {
    auto count = obj->propertyCount();
    for (int i = 0; i < count; ++i) {
        auto prop = obj->property(i);
        if (strcmp(prop.name(), name) == 0)
            return prop;
    }
    return QMetaProperty{};
}

class WithProperties {
    Q_GADGET
    Q_PROPERTY(QString name READ name WRITE setName)
    QString m_name;
public:
    QString name() const { return m_name; }
    void setName(const QString & name) { m_name = name; }
    QVariant property(const char * name) const {
        auto metaProperty = findMetaProperty(&staticMetaObject, name);
        if (metaProperty.isValid())
            return metaProperty.readOnGadget(this);
        auto it = m_properties.find(name);
        if (it != m_properties.end()) return *it;
        return QVariant{};
    }
    void setProperty(const char * name, const QVariant & value) {
        auto metaProperty = findMetaProperty(&staticMetaObject, name);
        if (metaProperty.isValid())
            return (void)metaProperty.writeOnGadget(this, value);
        m_properties[name] = value;
    }
    QList<QByteArray> dynamicPropertyNames() const {
        return m_properties.keys();
    }
private:
    QMap<QByteArray, QVariant> m_properties;
};

int main() {
    WithProperties prop;
    prop.setProperty("down", true);
    prop.setProperty("angle", 35.0);
    prop.setProperty("name", "foo");
    Q_ASSERT(prop.property("down") == true);
    Q_ASSERT(prop.property("angle") == 35.0);
    Q_ASSERT(prop.property("name") == "foo");
    Q_ASSERT(prop.dynamicPropertyNames().size() == 2);
}
#include "main.moc"
```